# Spring Batch- Ibatis Batch Item Writer - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring-batch, ibatis

I was trying to copy a data from one data source to another, used to Ibaitsbatchitemwriter class to do so. Record was got inserted into target database but end of the batch getting null pointer exception as below,

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.IbatisBatchItemWriter.write(IbatisBatchItemWriter.java:142)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)

but after adding the property assertupdates = fales i was not getting the error and then data is also got copied. but i was not convinced with the null pointer error, looks like am missing something in my config or so.

i use spring infra 2.2.4 and ibatis version 2.3.0.

```
<bean id="targetWriterDepAcct03"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.IbatisBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="targetDatabaseMap" />
        <property name="statementId" value="DepositAccountSqlMap.updtDepositAccount" />
        <property name="assertUpdates" value="false" />
    </bean>

<batch:job id="baseJob" abstract="true" restartable="true"
        job-repository="jobRepository" />
    <batch:job id="TboltSyncBatchJob">
        <batch:step id="CheckForConfigFileStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="CheckForConfigFile" />
            <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="SyncDataDepAcct03" />
            <batch:end on="FAILED" />
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="SyncDataDepAcct03">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="sourceReaderForDepAcct03" writer="targetWriterDepAcct03"
                    commit-interval="1000" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

That NPE is due to the fact that zero results were returned by the SqlMapClient.  If you don't need the number of records to be checked, you can turn that off.  If you need them checked, you'll want to look into why that query isn't returning any results.  You can see the code for the IbatisBatchItemWriter here: [IbatisBatchItemWriter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/2.2.x/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/IbatisBatchItemWriter.java).